# Natbib Chronological Parenthetical Citations

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'm using the `natbib` package along with the `chicago` bibliography style, however when creating a parenthetical citation in-text, the citations are ordered alphabetically instead of chronologically. Is there any package options that I would be able to use in order to achieve a parenthetical citation that is ordered chronologically?

Here is my preamble for reference:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[authoryear, round, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage[authoryear, round, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citep{cite1,cite2}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{firstpaper}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to even compile a bibliography using this method.

Comment: Could you please give an example of entries with keys `cite1` and `cite2`? Are we talking about two papers written by the same author(s) and published in the same year, where you happen to know that the entry `cite1` was published before entry `cite2`? If that's not the issue, then please tell us what is.

Comment: @Mico Apologies for the lack of detail. The citations are by different authors in different years and I want to order them from oldest to most recent.

Comment: To make sure I understand: Do you want only the groups of citations, or the citations *as well as* the bib entries, be sorted by year rather than alphabetically by authors' names? Incidentally, you providing two conflicting and mutually exclusive options to `natbib`: `numbers` and `authoryear` -- which citation style do you want?

Comment: @Mico I'd like only the groups of citations to be ordered chronologically, e.g. (cite1 (2003), cite2 (2007), cite3 (2009)) and the bibliography ordered alphabetically.

Comment: @Mico Again, sorry for the confusion, I would be using the `authoryear` citation style.

Comment: @Mico Do you think it can be done using the `natbib` package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the entries listed by `\citep` or `\citet` printed in the order in which they are input, rather than sorted alphabetically by authors' names, omit the option `sort&compress` when loading `natbib`.

If neither the `sort` nor the `sort&compress` options are set, the ordering of the citation callouts is determined by the way you sort the keys in the argument of the citation commands `\citep` and `\citet`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. I'm just writing my PhD thesis (in Economics) and this was becoming a major pain, thankfully you've relieved that pain and I can now continue.

Comment: @DavidClark - You're welcome! I got my Ph.D. in economics in 1991, by the way. Sadly, I didn't get to use LaTeX (let alone BibTeX) back then. Do make an effort to learn LaTeX and friends well; you'll find that writing papers becomes much easier if you develop a reasonable mastery of LaTeX. (I did!)

Comment: Fantastic! (I know that this is probably not the proper forum for chat but can I ask if you remained in academia?) I completely agree, it is an incredibly steep learning curve but given the results that LaTeX produce, it makes the effort well worth it!

Comment: @DavidClark - My first jobs after grad school were academic appointments, but I later went into central banking, which I find to be a marvelous mix of serious theoretical and applied economics (especially the macro, econometrics, finance, and banking subfields) and serious policy making. I have, fortunately, managed to stay in touch with scholarly academia; see if you can find a paper I co-authored in the July 2014 issue of the *Journal of Econometrics* (written, of course, in LaTeX -- what else?!). :-)

Comment: Ah, I found it. Congratulations on publishing, especially in such a prestigious journal! I'm more micro myself but I am especially interested in the econometrics concerned with accounting with slope heterogeneity at the moment. (Just reading your paper right now, it's very thought provoking!)

Comment: @DavidClark - Thanks for the compliments, and best wishes to you for a fulfilling and gratifying career in economics!